# Python Mysql Queary not returning results

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-connector

I have a DB and when I query a table I get 67 results. The SQL is:

```
SELECT lower(UserName) from Participants ;
```

I try to connect to the DB, and I get no connection errors.

```
def db_connect ():                                                                                                    
    try:                                                                                                              
        cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user=db_user, password=db_password,host=db_host,database=db_name)               
        return cnx                                                                                                    
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:                                                                              
        if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:                                                             
            print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")                                               
        elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:                                                                  
            print("Database does not exist")                                                                          
        else:                                                                                                         
            print(err)  

                                                                                                                      
def main():                                                                                                           
    cnx = db_connect()                                                                                                
    cursor = cnx.cursor()                                                                                             
    query = ("SELECT lower(UserName) from Participants ;")                                                            
    cursor.execute(query)                                                                                             
    print(cursor.rowcount)
```

It prints out -1 for rowcount. The connection to the DB appears to be working, the SQL is a simple query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try adding `cursor.fetchall()` before the `print(cursor.rowcount)`